# how to request components over network and render them reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, jsx

```
<Parent>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
</Parent>
```

how to go from the above state to

```
<Parent>
    <NewChild1 />
    <NewChild2 />
    <NewChild3 />
    ... and so on
</Parent>
```

how to do this when needed without preloading the NewChild components?
I want a way so that I can request a component when needed and render it inside the parent component in place of existing child components in react.

Just like facebook does - while in newsfeed it renders newsfeed, it doesn't have the profile page pre-loaded inside the JavaScript, when user clicks on profile, it fetches the profile component and renders it in place of the newsfeed component.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html). Due to lazy evaluation disabled children will not be rendered or even evaluated.

Here's an example of its usage:

```
<Parent>
    {(enableChild1) && 
        <Child1 {...child1props}/>
    }
    {(enableChild2) && 
        <Child2 {...child2props}/>
    }
</Parent>
```

But if you want indefinite number of children then consider using [Lists](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html).